# Chrome/google thinks I am from Saudi Arabia, how do I fix that?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, vpn

I have no idea why Chrome (or google) thinks I am from Saudi Arabia. At the first I thought maybe it was because some setting in my google account went wrong.
[image: Saudi Arabia chrome]

So I tried firefox and did not sign in but google still thinks I am from Saudi Arabia. [image: Saudi Arabia ff]

The other possible reason maybe the vpn server I used. But I login the server at US  [image: vpn]

and from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ it confirmed the ip is from US.

[image: whatismyipaddress]

So how do I fix it ? I want google to show my location at either US or China

Comment: Site preferences may allow access to location data which will override IP location data. Have you maybe said "allow" to "This site wants to know your location"?

Comment: Evidently your VPN provider doesn't honor your request for a US server.

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation of your IP address is set by the entity who controls the IP address, typically your provider.  You should open a support ticket and ask them about updating it.